# Survival plot in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, survival-analysis

I am trying to plot survival plots in a shiny app. Among other exploratory graphs, The UI has two `selectInput()` blocks where a user can select either the type of 'event' like Renal Failure, Plasmacytoma etc. and the second input is for calculation of the time interval. Part of the UI code is:

```
 selectInput(inputId="event",
             label = "Event",
             choices = c("RenalFailure","Plasmacytoma","RemissionStatusPreTx","RemissionStatusPostTx",
                                                    "TotalNoTherapy","ISS")
                          ),
                          selectInput(inputId="analysis",
                                      label="Period for analysis",
                                      choices=c("From date of transplant"="TD",
                                                "From date of relapse"="TD_R")

                          ),
```

In the server, the code that I am using is:

```
output$events <- renderPlot({
if(input$analysis=='TD'){
fit_RF <- survfit(Surv(TD,cenin_dead)~input$event,data=rlp_data)
ggsurvplot(fit_RF,risk.table = T,risk.table.height = 0.4,pval = T)
} else{
  fit_RF <- survfit(Surv(TD_R,relapse)~input$event,data=rlp_data)
  ggsurvplot(fit_RF,risk.table = T,risk.table.height = 0.4,pval = T)
}

})
```

This gives me an error `Error in model.frame.default: variable lengths differ (found for 'input$event')`. I Googled this error but honestly, couldn't make much of it. I tried providing the argument `na.action=na.omit` but no joy. If I hard code `input$event` to the actual value that it is returning (say, `RenalFailure`), the plot renders. Quite clueless here and would appreciate some guidance please.

Comment: Have a look at survival example within `highcharter` package http://jkunst.com/highcharter/hchart.html

Comment: Thanks for the input  @PorkChop , but my problem is not the `ggsurvplot()`. It's with the `survfit()` function. Something related to `input$event` I suspect. Thanks for the pointer to the `highcharter` package.

Comment: Does your code work without `shiny`?

Comment: Yes it does. Like I mentioned, if instead of `input$event` I use `RenalFailure`, the plot renders.

Comment: can you add a test for your client variables before you add them to plots. Such as: `if(!is.null(input$event)){}`

Comment: Try pasting your formula together. `survfit(as.formula(paste("Surv(TD_R,relapse)~", input$event)))`

Comment: @Gregor did that, and now I get an error `Error in paste: object 'input' not found`

Comment: @PorkChop status quo on testing for null :(

Comment: I'm making the assumption that the allowed strings for input$event are actual names of columns in the data frame. Rather than using, `input$event` in your formula, try `rlp_data[[input$evet]]`

Comment: @jamieRowen I tried what you suggested but this too throws an error `Error in .subset2: attempt to select less than one element in get1index`

Comment: @jamieRowen Correction to my last. The error I get is `Error in ( function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x, i, exact = exact): object 'input' not found`. I just copied your suggestion which has a typo.

Comment: @Dhiraj Hi yes, sorry I noticed the typo after it was too late to edit it. Strange error that `input` can not be found. The reason your initial attempt doesn't work is because `input$event` is a character, not being treated as a column name in your data frame. Which is why when you change it to a specific value it does work. I tested my solution outside of a shiny app and it works fine. If you can update your question with the full example to play around with I might be able to better track down what's going on. You could also search around for `eval deparse substitute` which might help

Comment: So what does `print(str(input))` display when that code it inserted at a point where you would expect it to have a value?

Comment: @42 the output of `print(str(input$analysis))` is `chr "TD"` and the output of `print(str(input$event))` is `chr "RenalFailure"` . @jamieRowen I am afraid the data pertains to healthcare and there are some issues in sharing it.